# Use a Search String to Locate a Cell

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets using Google Apps Script, I would like to obtain the value of cell R33 as a search string (easy), find the next instance of that search string in S:S (I'm stumped), then activate the cell in which the value was found (easy). In particular, I can't figure out how to do a simple search (essentially a vlookup). I've tried looping through the column and comparing like this:

```
function Vlookupscript( name, sheet, columnIndexWithNames, rowIndexToStart ) {    
  var maxRows = sheet.getLastRow() - 1;
  var range = sheet.getRange( rowIndexToStart, columnIndexWithNames, maxRows );
  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var index = -1;
  var cell; 
  var value;

  for ( var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++ ) {
    cell = range.getCell( i, 1 );
    value = cell.getValue();
    if ( value === name ) {
      index = i;
    }
  }
  return index;
}
```

where name is the value to search for.

However, I'm getting no output at all, even at the end of the loop using `logger.log(i)`. I'm sure there is a simpler way; for instance, could I load a column as an array and search that array, get the index, then activate the cell with the corresponding index?

Answer (score 2):

There is a much faster way. Currently you are invoking the SpreadsheetApp each time you want to check a value, which takes some time. First of all, you should probably do `maxRows = sheet.getLastRow()` and get rid of the `- 1`

I will asume that `name` is the value you wish to search for. So you can then do the following

```
values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('S:S').getValues()
for (i = 0; i = values.lenght; i++){
  if (values[i][0] == name) {
    sheet.getRange(i+1, 19).activate()
    return
  }
}
```

you can also do the values with

`values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange(1,19,maxRows-1,1).getValues()`

provided that you changed to loose the `- 1` for the `maxRows` variable. This will go through all the values and if the value matches then it sets the cell as active